# Recovering $a+b+\cdots$ from $\exp(a)+\exp(b)+\cdots$ for $a,b,\ldots\in\mathbb N$

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function

In a problem I working on, I have the following value $$ y = f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n) = \varphi^{a_1} + \varphi^{a_2} + \cdots + \varphi^{a_n} \enspace, $$
for $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\in\{0,1,\ldots\}$ and $\varphi = 1 - 1/m$ for $m$ an integer greater than 1. I am supposed, given $y$, to recover $$ x = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n \enspace.$$
I am able to show that the $x$ is unique when the $a_i$'s are whole numbers. For this question, I consider $x$ to be the "inverse function" of $y$, which makes sense somewhat since they are both symmetric in the $a_i$'s.

I have two solutions but none of them is satisfatory (one is an approximation and the other is computationally demanding and suffers from numerical issues).

**Solution 1 (using truncated Taylor expansion):**
$$ x = (y-n)/\ln(\varphi) + O(m^{-1}) \enspace. $$
The problem with this solution is that the error is high when $m$ is small, and I do not control $m$.

**Solution 2 (Tracing the hypersurface):**

Basically trying out all the integers lying (close) to the hypersurface defined by the implicit equation of $y$ until we find an exact match (lying exactly on the hypersurface). The problem with this solution is that it can take too much time if the $a_i$'s are huge, even if we exploit the symmetry that the order of $a_i$ doesn't matter. Additionally, $y$ lies between 0 and 2, and tiny changes in $y$ may lead to big changes in $x$ (the function may be numerically unstable). Furthermore, due to the use of floating point representation, we output the point *closest* to the hypersufrace instead.

**One more problem**
In addition to the above challenges, what I am actually given is a perturbed value of $y$: $y+\text{noise}$. So I am also interested in understanding the behaviour of a given algorithm for extracting $x$ under perturbation.

So my questions are:

> Is this function known under a name?  Has it (or its "inverse") been
>   studied before?  Is there a direct formula (not necessarily "closed-form") to compute the "inverse" than
>   the two ways I proposed?  What is the behaviour of the inverse under
>   perturbation?

Comment: Are the $a_i$ unique? I don't see how you can show that $x$ is unique otherwise; since the powers of $\phi$ are all rational, there's an arbitrary 'rational' relation among them.  For instance, take $m=3$, $\phi=\frac23$, $\phi^2=\frac49$; then $3\phi+2=9\phi^2$, so the $a$-vectors $\langle 0, 0, 1, 1, 1\rangle$ and $\langle 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2\rangle$ yield the same value.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The $a_i$ are not unique, but I meant that $x$ is unique for fixed $n$. In the example you gave $n$ is different.

Comment: I should probably add that $n$ is known and is given to the inverse function as input.

Comment: I'd still love to see the argument for uniqueness; I can imagine ways that it might be, but it feels like there should be 'padded' versions of my example that give identical results.

Comment: with $m=3$ and $n=5$, $(1,1,3,3,3)$ and $(2,2,2,2,2)$ give the same $y = 20/9$ but their $x$ are different ($11$ and $10$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a conceptual proof that the answer can't be unique, along with a specific example to illustrate.  I'll rewrite your (multi)set $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ as $\{m_1\cdot d_1, m_2\cdot d_2, \ldots, m_t\cdot d_t\}$; that is, the values $d_i$ (degree) with multiplicity $m_i$ (e.g., the multiset $\{0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2\}$ with $n=6$ corresponds to $\{2\cdot 0, 1\cdot 1, 3\cdot 2\}$.

Now, consider the polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^nx^{a_i}$ $= \sum_{j=1}^tm_jx^{d_j}$.

You say that you know the value $n$; this value is just $p(1)$. You also know the value $p(\varphi)$; and you want to know the value $\sum_i a_i=\sum_j m_jd_j$. This value is just $p'(1)$.

But now, consider $r(x)=p(x)+q(x)$, where we've chosen $q(x)$ such that $q(1)=q(\varphi)=0$.  This will have the same values at $1$ and $\varphi$, but it won't (generically) have the same derivative at $1$; this means that your hoped-for sum isn't guaranteed to be unique.

For a specific example, consider $\varphi=\dfrac23$; one candidate polynomial is $q(x)=3(x-1)(x-\varphi) = 3x^2-5x+2$.  For simplicity, we can take $p(x)=5x$, so $r(x)=3x^2+2$.  In other words, the multisets of $a_i$s are $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}$ and $\{0, 0, 2, 2, 2\}$. These have exactly the same number of elements, and in each case the sum $\sum_i\varphi^{a_i}=\dfrac{10}{3}$. But $\sum_ia_i=5$ for the first multiset and $6$ for the second.

OTOH, if it's known that $m_i\lt m$ for all $i$ and an exact value for $p(\varphi)$ is known, then the full multiset can be recovered.  This is because the expression acts as a sort of 'base-$m$ expansion': consider multiplying $p(\varphi)$ by $m^{d_1}$, where (for convenience) $d_1$ is the largest degree. Then the term $m_i\varphi^{d_i}$ becomes $m_im^{d_1-d_i}(m-1)^{d_i}$; this will be divisible by $m$ for all $d_i\lt d_1$, and if $d_i=d_1$ then the expression is congruent to $(-1)^{d_1}m_1\pmod m$; this $p(\varphi)$ in lowest terms is guaranteed to have a denominator of $m^{d_1}$; the expression $m^{d_1}p(\varphi)$ is manifestly integral, and since it's nonzero mod $m$ no smaller power of $m$ will produce an integer.  This means that the sequence of $m_i$ and $d_i$ can be extracted by finding the first $d$ with $m^dp(\varphi)$ integral, setting $d_1=d$ and $m_1=(-1)^dm_dp(\varphi)\bmod m$, and subtracting $m_1\varphi^{d_1}$ from $y=p(\varphi)$, and iterating.

Finally, in the regime where $m\gg m_i$ for all $i$, we can take advantage of the special nature of the value we're after to get an excellent approximate solution.  Remember that the sought-after value ($x$ in OP's notation) is just $p'(1)$; but for large $m$, we have $\varphi=1-\frac1m\approx 1$, so we can use the classical approximation that $p'(1)=\dfrac{p(1)-p(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$. In the notation of this problem, this says that $x\approx m(n-y)+O(m^{-1})$ (this is a simpler version of OP's Taylor series approximation).  Better yet, we can get good bounds on the error: by the Taylor theorem with remainder, we have $x=m(n-y)+m^{-1}p''(\zeta)$ for some $\varphi\leq\zeta\leq 1$.  But note that (writing in terms of the $a_i$ for convenience) since all the $a_i$ are positive, $p''(\zeta)\leq p''(1)$ for all such $\zeta$; what's more, the second derivative of $x^{a_i}$ is $\dfrac{a_i(a_i-1)}{2}x^{a_i-2}\leq \dfrac{a_i^2}{2}x^{a_i-1}\leq\frac12a_i^2$.  What's more, we have $\sum_ia_i^2\leq (\sum_ia_i)^2$ (we can do much better than this, but this is fine), so we know that $p''(\zeta)\leq \frac12n^2$ (and in fact, it will generally be much less than this value).  Thus, the maximum error in the approximation $x\approx m(n-y)$ is $\frac12n^2m^{-1}$; over the regime listed by OP in comments, this is much smaller than 1 and so the nearest integer to $m(n-y)$ will be the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My proof worked for $e$, and I assumed it would work for $\varphi$, but you bypassed it by virtue of $\varphi$ being a rational number. However, I am interested in the cases in which $n\ll m$ ($n$ is usually less than 10, while $m$ is greater than $2^{10}$), but your proof seems to generate counter-examples for $n>m$. Can you give me a hint/advice on whether it seems plausible that uniqueness holds when $n< m$?

Comment: To elaborate: in the proposed polynomial representation of multisets, there is an implicit condition that the (non-negative) coefficients $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_t$ sum to $n$, consequently $m_i \leqslant n$ for any $i$. However, from the construction of $q$, which depends on the $\varphi$ being rational, we see that the leading coefficient in $q$ is $m$. Thus, $m$ must be less than $n$. Suppose we will only consider cases in which $m>n$ instead. In that case the polynomial $q$ is not viable. Is there, then, any alternative construction which works for $m>n$?

Comment: @M.Alaggan Uniqueness does hold in this case - in fact, you only need $m_i\lt m$ for all $i$. I had an argument for this in the case where all the $m_i$ were 1, but that argument actually generalizes; I'll write it up shortly. (Unfortunately, it may not lead to a particularly good algorithm for your regime of $m$; since $\varphi\approx 1$, all the powers of $\varphi$ are close to each other, so any numeric algorithms will be innately sensitive to rounding error. )

Comment: Thank you very much for your extended answer. It is awesome. I believe that the valid "encodings" (those which correspond to a polynomial $p(\varphi)$ with $p(1)=n$) are finite (given $m_i<m$ and some application-specific upper bound on the $a_i$'s), and the minimum distance between any two encodings is $\varphi^{m-1}$. Therefore, it might be possible to come up with an "error correction" of some sort to still be able to recover $p'(1)$ given $p(\varphi)+\text{noise}$.

Comment: I realized I was mistaken (about the minimum distance) but apparently comments cannot be edited after 5 minutes of posting them. One last thing: let $y=p(\varphi)$ for some $p$ (a valid encoding of a multiset). Do you think that, given $y'=y+{}$ noise, it is possible to efficiently find a valid encoding (a polynomial $g$) such that $|g(\varphi)-y'|$ is (almost) minimal? Numerical evidence suggests that the distance $|g'(1)-p'(1)|$ grows linearly with $|g(\varphi)-p(\varphi)|$, so I may be able to approximate $x$ this way. Thanks!